# apply function and top_n doesn't work well together

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a simple dataframe `df` in R:

```
year, var1, var2, var3
1990, 23, 1, 133
1991, 25, 3, 120
1992, 28, 2, 110
...
```

The data goes on for hundreds of rows.

I want to select top 10 values for var1, var2, var3 using `apply()` and `top_n()` in R, like this:

```
df %>%
 select(var1, var2, var3) %>%
 apply(2, top_n(10), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I get the error:
`Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars"): no applicable method for "tbl_vars" applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

I thought that `apply` could help me avoid using a for loop to get the top 10 values variable by variable but I wasn't able to do so.

It seems a simple problem, but I haven't found good answers online. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`top_n` expects a data.frame as input whereas when we do the looping with `apply`, `MARGIN = 2`, it is looping over each column i.e. a `vector`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfc(c('var1', 'var2', 'var3'), ~ df %>%
                                 select(.x) %>%
                                 top_n(10) %>%
                                  slice(seq_len(10)))
```

Also, according to `?top_n`, it is superseded by `slice_max/slice_min`

```
map(c('var1', 'var2', 'var3'), ~ df %>%
                                 select(.x) %>%
                                 slice_max(!! rlang::sym(.x), n = 10))
```

Using a reproducible example with `iris`

```
map_dfc(names(iris)[1:4], ~
          iris %>% 
              select(.x) %>% 
              top_n(10) %>% 
              slice(seq_len(10)))

map(names(iris)[1:4], ~
          iris %>% 
              select(.x) %>% 
              slice_max(!! rlang::sym(.x), n = 10))
```

---

Or with `summarise` with `across` and `sort`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     summarise(across(starts_with('var'), ~ 
       list(head(sort(., decreasing = TRUE), 10)))) %>%
     unnest(c(everything())
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is better to have data in long format which makes it very easy to do such operations.

You can use `pivot_longer` to get data in long format then for every column you can select top 10 values based on the value in the column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -year) %>% group_by(name) %>%  top_n(10, value)
```